# android studio workspace layout changed

Tags: android, android-studio

I'am new in android development and recently I've installed android studio and it worked perfectly for a couple of days, but now it's layout has changed such that I cannot buttons like the one of avd, sdk etc. How do I reset to the default layout, because I've tried for a couple of times going at menu > window > restore default layout. But it didn't work.

Thanks in advance. Sorry for my poor English.

This is how it looks like now:

[image]

Comment: go to (windows) in top bar than ->restore default layout

Comment: thanks, but I tried that for a couple of times but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Click on **VIEW** menu and after that from dropdown click on **ToolBar** , **Tool Button**  and **Navigation Bar** . After this you will see all the buttons etc.

Comment: ooh thanks, but that returned only few buttons, still many of them like the avd and sdk button are  missing